# A Cary Grant's self-citation?

Tags: north-by-northwest, bringing-up-baby

Is Cary Grant one-arm lifting of Eva Marie Saint on the upper berth in the final segment of Hitchcock's North by Northwest a citation of himself lifting with one arm Katharine Hepburn in the final scene of Howard Hawk's Bringing up Baby?

---

Here's the two segments:

[Bringing Up Baby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B16rhVK5Av0) (starting at 2:44)

[North by Northwest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPt-4Nwght0) (starting at 0:12)

Comment: I think this is a perfect example of a question that would be greatly improved with a screenshot :)

Comment: @fabriced: it's a nice idea. I am not sure how to do it but I can give it a try

Comment: Couldn't find screenshots of the exact moments in question but added extracts of the final segments (once again, thank you YouTube!)

Comment: I'm gonna say no. Firstly, the films are entirely different genres and directors  and, secondly, in North by Northwest.... **he does no such thing**. Just watch it closer, at best best just holding her hand (perhaps with a small assist) as she helps *herself* into the bunk

Comment: @Paulie_D: the difference of genres and directors is irrelevant. In fact the berth scene is (in the movie) the direct continuation of that on Mount Rushmore, where he was holding her to avoid her falling down. Which is exactly what had happened, obviously in a different setting and different circumstances, with Katharine Hepburn.